# Do onomatopoeias have more intrinsic meaning than other words have?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

I was taught that words are arbitrary sounds used to represent an abstract concept. In the case of onomatopoeias, are they not so arbitrary? For example the word "buzz" roughly sounds like a bee buzzing. Can the same be said for any other words, that their name does have a special meaning and isn't arbitrary?

Comment: There is truth in the claim, but as is almost always the case, not the whole truth. It's a rule of thumb. Sadly, teachers often fail to point out this fact when they introduce a 'rule', which leads intelligent and trusting students into problems way down the line. Obviously, onomatopoeic words are not totally arbitrary in form (via sound). And probably, there were other reasons why certain utterances, later written down (in languages using alphabets) using symbols to attempt a written representation of how they were spoken, were applied to various referents.

Comment: Please also visit [linguistics.se]

Answer (score 1):

I think they are still quite arbitrary, as the chosen onomatopoeia depends on the speaker's language to start with.

For you "buzz" may sound like the bee, but a Dutchman uses the word "zoemen", the "zoem" reflecting the bee-sound to him (it is pronounced as "zoom").

A similar thing is true for the golden oriole (a bird), which is "wielewaal" in Dutch. The Latin name (oriolis oriolis), as well as the Dutch name are again onomatopoeias.

Since arguably we don't assume Dutch and birds bees make a different sound than English bees or birds , I would say that the "buzz" and "zoom" words that represent the bee's sound are still quite arbitrary and abstract, possibly not less than the word "table" is for the four-legged object.

(I admit the possibility has to be considered as a slight one... some people might end up with a very limited vocabulary according to the comment :P )

Comment: I wouldn't go that far. If I had to approximate the sound my table usually makes, I'd end up with the same word as I would for Halley's Comet.

Comment: +1. The specific *word* component of onomatopoeias are mostly arbitrary as evidenced by the many variations of "ha". They are inherently more connected to "reality" in the sense that they have to approximate literal sounds but there is more to a word than that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would like to add my view .

Onomatopoeic words  are just imitating sounds. For me, to ask  about an intrinsic meaning does not make much sense.
But the view that normal words are just arbitary sounds is, at least, naive. That may be true for the very first words of the very first human beings. But then there must be logic in the words otherwise 
Man would not be able to retain the meaning of thousands of words.

Whoever has a knowledge of etymology knows how much logic is in the vocabulary.